# Diferencias entre el uso del artículo en español y en inglés

Tags: artículos, comparación-de-idiomas

¿Cómo traducimos estas oraciones al inglés?

1. Tengo coche.
2. Tengo un coche.
3. Tengo el coche.

¿Es correcto?

1. I have a car (general statement)
2. I have one car (and not two, for example)
3. I have the car (the car you already know about)

¿O no son completamente equivalentes? ¿Puede "tengo un coche" también significar "I have a car"? En inglés, no podemos usar "I have the car" sin contexto que describa que es el específico coche a que referimos. ¿El español funciona de la misma manera?

¿Hay algo especial con la palabra "coche"? Alguien me ha dicho que para expresar "I have a glass" tengo que decir "tengo un vaso" y no "tengo vaso". ¿Por qué?

Comment: All your examples about a car are correct. The situation with the glass  is exactly the same and your friend is wrong. "Tengo vaso" is correct, however usually you only need one so it is more common to say "tengo un vaso". Consider that someone at at party says: "who needs a glass?" the answer in spanish could be "No gracias, yo ya **tengo vaso**".

Comment: @DGaleano your comment is a nice bit of information. Fancy converting it into an answer so you can expand it? Thanks!

Comment: @fedorqui sometimes when I have something to say but it is not a full answer I just comment. In this case I think my comment is a "nice bit of information" but there is a lot to say about the use or not of the article that I feel this should be a _yay's type_ answer with lots of examples. I just don't have the time today. I don't mind someone else doing it.

Answer (score 2):

La clave está en la *hipotética* pregunta a la que responde cada una de las frases:

1. ¿Necesitas coche para venir?
    *No gracias, ya **tengo coche***
2. ¿Cuántos coches tienes?
    *Tengo **un coche** solamente*
3. ¿Quién de vosotros tenía el coche?
    *Yo tengo **el coche***

Tus ejemplos con *coche* son correctos.

1. I have a car (**indeterminado**)
2. I have one car (**numeral**)
3. I have the car (**determinado o específico**)

> ¿Puede "tengo un coche" también
>   significar "I have a car"?

Sí, siempre y cuando, siga siendo indeterminado. Por ejemplo:

- *Tengo **un coche** que es una maravilla.*

  Seguimos sin determinar. No sabemos cuántos tengo. Ni cuál de ellos es una maravilla.

Sí es cierto que, cuando usamos *'un'*, estamos haciendo referencia a *un candidato de varios* posibles, **pero seguimos sin determinar** cuál.

Comprobación:

¿**Tienes** coche?
*Sí, tengo un coche que es una maravilla* (ok)

¿**Cuántos** coches tienes?
*tengo un coche que es una maravilla* (ko)

¿Quién de vosotros tenía **el** coche?
*Yo tengo un coche que es una maravilla* (ko)

Answer (score 2):

La primera y la tercera se traducen como es esperable:

> Tengo coche = I have a car
>
> Tengo el coche = I have the car

En el caso de *un coche*, la palabra "un" es funcionalmente polisémica. Puede significar dos cosas y por lo tanto traducirse distinto:

**1. Adjetivo numeral**

> Un - dos - tres - ...

Aquí estamos hablando de la cantidad de coches, en este caso uno (1). Se dice que "un" es *apócope* de "uno" (igual que buen-bueno, ningún-ninguno, etc.). Por ejemplo:

> María tiene dos motos y Juan tiene **un** coche. = Maria has two motorcycles and Juan has **one** car.

**2. artículo indeterminado**

> Un - una - unos - unas:

El coche del que estamos hablando puede ser cualquiera, porque no ha sido mencionado antes en el contexto o porque es un concepto genérico. Por ejemplo:

> La Ford sacó **un** coche espectacular = The Ford put on sale **a** spectacular car

Aquí en realidad no es uno, son miles.

Como te imaginarás, detectar la diferencia es muy difícil, depende del contexto. Lo mismo ocurre a la inversa: *I have a car* se puede traducir a veces como "Tengo coche" y otras veces como "tengo un coche". Entonces finalmente las posibles traducciones quedan así:

> Tengo coche = I have a car - Cuando es incontable (Pidió café, hizo clases)
>
> Tengo un coche = I have a car - Cuando es cualquiera (Pidió un café, hizo unas clases)
>
> Tengo un coche = I have one car - Cuando es una cantidad (un café, dos cafés, tres cafés)
>
> Tengo el coche = I have the car - Cuando es específico y conocido (el coche de mis sueños)